# How to condense 3 IF loops with the toggle() method in Vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, toggle

I have created this lightbulb exercise that toggles the SRC of the lightbulb, the background color, as well as the color of the text. As an extra challenge, I'm trying to see if I can condense my code using the toggle() method as I have 3 separate functions. Does anyone know if this is possible and how I could accomplish this?

```
<h1 class="title-text" id="title-text">Click the lightbulb to turn it on or off!</h1>
        <img id="lightbulb" onclick="toggleLight();toggleColor();toggleText()" src="/personal-projects/pic_bulbon1.gif">
        <script>
            let lightbulb = document.getElementById("lightbulb");
            let titleText = document.getElementById("title-text");
            
            function toggleLight() {
                if (lightbulb.src.match("bulbon1")) {
                    lightbulb.src = "/personal-projects/pic_bulboff1.gif"
                } else {
                    lightbulb.src = "/personal-projects/pic_bulbon1.gif"
                }
            }

            function toggleColor() {
                if (lightbulb.src.match("bulboff1")) {
                    document.body.style.background = "black";
                } else {
                    document.body.style.background = "#FEDD00";
                }
            }

            function toggleText() {
                if (lightbulb.src.match("bulboff1")) {
                    titleText.style.color = "white";
                } else {
                    titleText.style.color = "black";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The If loops work fine. I just want to know how I could use toggle if its possible. All the tutorials I find for this type of thing involve jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using toggle method

You want to first create a class for toggling in your css. Each element you want to toggle should have a default state and a toggled state. Toggling will add/remove a single class.

See snippet below

### Snippet

```js
const LightBulb = document.getElementById("lightbulb");

const toggleLight = () => {
  LightBulb.classList.toggle("lightBulbOn");
  document.body.classList.toggle("bodyLightOn");
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

body,
body .title-text {
  color: white;
}

body.bodyLightOn {
  background-color: #fedd00;
}

body.bodyLightOn .title-text {
  color: black;
}

#lightbulb::before {
  content: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b4/Gluehlampe_01_KMJ.png/340px-Gluehlampe_01_KMJ.png");
}

.lightBulbOn::before {
  content: url("https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/HaPnm6P7TZhPQGGUxtDjAg-320-80.jpg") !important;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title-text" id="title-text">Click the lightbulb to turn it on or off!</h1>
<div id="lightbulb" class="" onclick="toggleLight();">
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/devnetkc/pen/OJEREWr)